# Find records that do not have matching closing value

Tags: mysql

Sorry for unclear title, i am having trouble formulating the right question subject.
Hopefully the details will help you understand more clearly the issue i am facing.

I have a table with the following schema:

```
+----+----------+-----+
| ID |  Status  | PID | Time ...
+----+----------+-----+---
|  1 |  STARTED |  10 |
|  2 |  STARTED |  12 |
|  3 |  ENDED   |  10 |
|  4 |  STARTED |  18 |
|  5 |  STARTED |  21 |
|  6 |  ENDED   |  12 |
+----+----------+-----+
```

Every time a process starts, an entry containing its `PID` set to 'STARTED' `Status` in database.
Every time a process finishes its job, another entry containing its `PID` gets written to the database with the `Status` value of 'ENDED'.
A process with same 'PID' can start once again after finish.

I would appreciate if someone can guide me in the right direction to a query which will return all the PID's that have started but not (yet) completed.

Desired output:

```
+----+----------+-----+
| ID |  Status  | PID | Time ...
+----+----------+-----+---
|  4 |  STARTED |  18 |
|  5 |  STARTED |  21 |
+----+----------+-----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the process with some PID was started, but was not finished, there is only one record for it.

```
SELECT pid
FROM table
GROUP BY pid
HAVING COUNT(pid) = 1
```

If process with the same `PID`can start/finish more than once, working process have odd records count.

```
HAVING 1 = (COUNT(pid) MOD 2)
```

Having PIDs list you can easily obtain the whole records.

Comment: While this solution returns the desired PID, doing `GROUP BY` does not return the last record. it would be nice to know the Time that the process STARTED.

Comment: I mean if the process has started for the second time, and did not finish, your solution will return only the time of the first process run.

Comment: What the question, such the answer. My solution do not return time at all, because time example data do not present in your question at all.

Comment: Having PID, find MAX(time) for it. Having time, get whole record.